# Find the maximum value of $x^{\alpha}y^{\beta}$ subject to the constraints $x+2y \le 2$ and $x > 0$ and $y > 0$.

Tags: calculus, optimization

**The Statement of the Problem:**

Given real numbers $\alpha > 0$, $\beta > 0$, $\alpha + \beta \le 1$, find the maximum value of $x^{\alpha}y^{\beta}$ subject to the constraints $x+2y \le 2$ and $x > 0$ and $y > 0$ (notice that these are strict inequalities). Justify why your answer is a global maximum (notice that the constraint set is not closed).

**My Questions:**

Do all the constraints need to be strict inequalities to satisfy Slater's Condition? At first glance, I was thinking that this is a problem dealing with Slater's Condition, but that non-strict inequality threw me off. Regardless, I'm still confused as to what that means for the problem. I have in my notes that if the constraint set satisfies Slater's Condition, then any global maximum satisfies Kuhn-Tucker Conditions. This also means that I do not need to check to see if my objective function is concave, which is nice. So, should I just proceed to tackle this as a normal KT problem?

Comment: No, only nonlinear constraints must satisfy strict inequality. Polyhedral constraints may be non-strict. Note by the way that your objective is concave, so this is a convex optimization problem.

Comment: There is no need for $x>0$ and $y>0$ to be strict anyway.

Comment: So, in this case, Slater's Condition is satisfied? And why do you think it says "notice that these are strict inequalities" if it doesn't matter?

Comment: Right. Slater's condition requires strict inequality only for the non-polyhedral constraints. The only reason I can think of why they want you to notice that the inequality is strict is that it avoids having to deal with the lack of differentiability at the origin. But given that the objective is zero at the origin, and presumably positive at least *somewhere* else, I don't see why that's really an issue.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. So, do I proceed with a Kuhn-Tucker approach, or is not that even necessary? I just tried it and it didn't really work. Do I only need to check the gradient of the objective function and see if the critical points are in my constraint set? Hmm. I'm a bit lost here...